# How To Fix SpriteRenderers Not Changing at Runtime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I am trying to change an element of a 2d character at runtime. I've used the code below and it doesn't seem to change the sprite of the character at all. No errors or anyhting but the physical sprite doesn't change. I have used Debug.Log to see if the methods are being called (which they are). I've also included some screenshots of how it is inside of inspector.

Here is what I have so far.

InventoryPanel.cs

```
public CharacterAppeance ca;


if (item.location == ItemLocation.Boot)//This is set in ItemData.ca
{
    ca.SetBoot(item.appaerance[0], item.appaerance[1]);
}
```

CharacterApperance.cs

```
public SpriteRenderer leg1ArmorRenderer;
public SpriteRenderer leg2ArmorRenderer;
public SpriteRenderer pelvisArmorRenderer;
public SpriteRenderer shin1ArmorRenderer;
public SpriteRenderer shin2ArmorRenderer;

public void SetBoot(Sprite leg, Sprite shin)
{
    leg1ArmorRenderer.sprite = leg;
    leg2ArmorRenderer.sprite = leg;
    shin1ArmorRenderer.sprite = shin; 
    shin2ArmorRenderer.sprite = shin;
}
```

ItemData.cs

```
public Sprite[] appaerance;
```

Itemdata in Inspector: http://prntscr.com/nbvgj9

CharacterApperance in Inspector: http://prntscr.com/nbvh7w

InventoryPanel in Inspector: http://prntscr.com/nbvhlr

Thank you all who help :)

Comment: Does you charakter have an animator? If you change your sprites in any animation of your animator, you can't change them in script anymore.

Comment: It does any work around for that?

Comment: The only workaround i know is resetting your sprites every frame in `LateUpdate()`, since LateUpdate gets called after the animator does it's thing. Kinda sucks though that there aren't really many better options